# page reloading within few second and stopped automatically when a data added to the database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a file with structure like this:

```
    <?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id_history FROM tb_history");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$VariableA = count($data);
$variableB = $VariableA + 1;

if($VariableA == $VariableB)
{
<script>clearInterval();</script>
}
else
{
<script>setInterval()</script>
}

?>
```

I'm trying to make a page refresh automatically within few second and stop refreshing when a new data added to table tb_history. can you suggest me better algorithm??

Thank You...

Comment: dont you think you should echo those `<script>clearInterval();</script>` ? and instead doing this just update by ajax  no useless reloading and less load on server. BTW check this [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

Comment: and why are you doing this refresh ? prefer ajax